# I cannot install "photosynthesis" package

Tags: r

For some reason, I dont seem to be able to install the package.
I tried to install it today but I get a couple of errors including the final "Warning in install.packages :
installation of package ‘photosynthesis’ had non-zero exit status"

I have installed other packages and that one is the only one that seems to have a problem.
Some colleagues have been able to install it so I do not know what I am doing wrong

Some help would be really appreciated it

Edit: Full error message

```
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/rlibs/4.0.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘cli’, ‘lifecycle’, ‘rlang’, ‘vctrs’, ‘ggplot2’


  There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
          binary source needs_compilation
cli        3.2.0  3.6.0              TRUE
lifecycle  1.0.1  1.0.3             FALSE
rlang      1.0.2  1.0.6              TRUE
vctrs      0.4.1  0.5.2              TRUE
ggplot2    3.3.5  3.4.0             FALSE

  Binaries will be installed
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/cli_3.2.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1255499 bytes (1.2 MB)
downloaded 1.2 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/rlang_1.0.2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1718546 bytes (1.6 MB)
downloaded 1.6 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/vctrs_0.4.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1569486 bytes (1.5 MB)
downloaded 1.5 MB

package ‘cli’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘rlang’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘vctrs’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\quesadaa\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpMBWG1b\downloaded_packages
installing the source packages ‘lifecycle’, ‘ggplot2’, ‘photosynthesis’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/lifecycle_1.0.3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 106854 bytes (104 KB)
downloaded 104 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/ggplot2_3.4.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3148426 bytes (3.0 MB)
downloaded 3.0 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/photosynthesis_2.1.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2678855 bytes (2.6 MB)
downloaded 2.6 MB

'\\ad.helsinki.fi\home\q\quesadaa\Documents'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
* installing *source* package 'lifecycle' ...
** package 'lifecycle' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace 'rlang' 1.0.2 is being loaded, but >= 1.0.6 is required
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> loadNamespace -> namespaceImport -> loadNamespace
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'lifecycle'
* removing 'C:/rlibs/4.0.5/lifecycle'
* restoring previous 'C:/rlibs/4.0.5/lifecycle'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘lifecycle’ had non-zero exit status
'\\ad.helsinki.fi\home\q\quesadaa\Documents'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
* installing *source* package 'ggplot2' ...
** package 'ggplot2' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace 'vctrs' 0.4.1 is being loaded, but >= 0.5.0 is required
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> loadNamespace -> namespaceImport -> loadNamespace
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'ggplot2'
* removing 'C:/rlibs/4.0.5/ggplot2'
* restoring previous 'C:/rlibs/4.0.5/ggplot2'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ggplot2’ had non-zero exit status
'\\ad.helsinki.fi\home\q\quesadaa\Documents'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
* installing *source* package 'photosynthesis' ...
** package 'photosynthesis' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
Error in parse(outFile) : 
  C:/Users/quesadaa/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp4UkMHR/R.INSTALL31846c817b0d/photosynthesis/R/bake-par.R:22:12: unexpected '>'
21:   # Set units ----
22:   .x = .x |>
               ^
ERROR: unable to collate and parse R files for package 'photosynthesis'
* removing 'C:/rlibs/4.0.5/photosynthesis'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘photosynthesis’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: While I understand your plight, "non-zero exit status" could be **anything**. Please show _actual_ installation code, the actual error message(s), and all text in between. Typically there is something clear in the middle such as "package 'X' is version 'this' and and 'that' is required", in which case the response is typically: restart R/RStudio into a fresh (no-packages-loaded) instance, install the problematic package, then reattempt installing the original package.

Comment: I added the whole error message

Comment: I suggest you write a [bug report](https://github.com/cdmuir/photosynthesis/issues/new/choose) to the author, telling them that they need to upgrade the minimum version of R from [4.0.0](https://github.com/cdmuir/photosynthesis/blob/main/DESCRIPTION#L13) to 4.1.0. They are using the `|>` operator which was introduced into R in 4.1.0 (go to https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/NEWS.html, search for `|>`, and look for the furthest-down reference indicating *"R now provides a simple native forward pipe syntax `|>`"*, within 4.1.0).

Comment: In the interim, if you upgrade your local R to 4.1.0 or newer, the problem should resolve.

Comment: But there is also a clear example in your error code that I mentioned earlier: `namespace 'rlang' 1.0.2 is being loaded, but >= 1.0.6 is required` says that you need to update that package as well. Restart R completely (no `.Rprofile`, no `.Rdata`) and update `rlang` as well.

Comment: Thanks I will upgrade and notify the authors through GitHub